# Electric field for two coaxial, infinite thin, infinite long cylinders

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

**Problem:**
calculate the Electric Field for two coaxial (along z-Axis), infinite thin and infinite long charged cylinders with $r_1 < r_2$ and surface charge density $-\sigma \frac{r_1}{r_2}$ respectively $\sigma>0$.

**Solution:**
So from Gauss follows that
$$\int_{\partial V} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{F}=\int_{\partial V} Edf = E\cdot M = 4\pi Q_{in} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \vec{E}=4\pi\frac{Q_{in }}{M} \tag{1}$$

wheres $M$ is the surface area of our Gauss-Cylinder
$$M=2\pi r h \tag{2}$$

We have
$$Q_{in}=\begin{cases}0, & r<r_1\\ 2\pi r_1 h\cdot \sigma', & r_1\leq r < r_2 \\ 0, &r_2 \leq r\end{cases} \tag{3}$$

Whereas $\sigma'=\sigma \frac{r_1}{r_2}$

Now we get, using (1):

$$\vec{E}=\begin{cases}0, & r < r_1\\ 4\pi\frac{r_1}{r}\sigma', &r_1\leq r < r_2 \\ 0, &r_2\leq r \end{cases} \tag{4}$$

For the potential,

**Question:**

So first of all, I'm confused by their use of the symbol $\sigma$. Where I used $\sigma'$, they just used $\sigma$. Their official solution is:

$$Q_{in}=\begin{cases}0, & r<r_1\\ 2\pi r_1 h\cdot \sigma, & r_1\leq r < r_2 \\ 0, &r_2 \leq r\end{cases} \tag{5}$$

$$\vec{E}=\begin{cases}0, & r < r_1\\ \frac{\sigma}{r}r_1, &r_1\leq r < r_2 \\ 0, &r_2\leq r \end{cases} \tag{6}$$

But I just can't see how they got their solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem means that the surface density of the inner cylinder is $\sigma$ and the surface density of the external cylinder is $\sigma'$.

Comment: hmm, I think they really did mean that the surface density is $\pm \sigma \frac{r_1}{r_2}$. The $\sigma > 0$ and the fact that we have a capacitor should indicate the $\pm$ - at least that's how I read it and their solution does match up with that (outer electric field vanishes). But then I'm still wondering what $\sigma$ should stand for.

Comment: If the surface density is the same on the two surfaces, the electric field outide is not zero as the outer surface is larger (i.e. the charge on it when you apply Gauss' law is bigger and you have a total charg which is not zero) while, if it's as I say, the total charge is zero.

Comment: I meant that the charge is the same, that implies that the density varies of course.

Comment: Were you able to get what they got?

Comment: Yes, if it's as I say I get the official solution

Comment: What system did you calculate in?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Did you use Gauss's Law in SI or CGI units?

Comment: I don't know what CGI is, but I just supposed that in your olution you put $4\pi\epsilon_0=1$